# Split rows in table using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have the following rows from a table in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|  ID          EntryType dt         price   |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 14          4         2012-11-07 0.025000 |
| 16          5         2012-11-07 0.026000 |
| 18          6         2012-11-07 0.026000 |
| 20          7         2012-11-07 0.026000 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

What I would like to do is spread the rows based on the EntryType (the EntryType doesn't change)

```
For EntryType = 4 (1 row)
For EntryType = 5 (2 row)
For EntryType = 6 (3 row)
For EntryType = 7 (9 row)
```

and the dt field will be incremented (in a Month interval), so the output looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| EntryType |    dt     | Price |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|         4 | 11/7/2012 | 0.024 |
|         5 | 12/7/2012 | 0.025 |
|         5 | 1/7/2013  | 0.025 |
|         6 | 2/7/2013  | 0.026 |
|         6 | 3/7/2013  | 0.026 |
|         6 | 4/7/2013  | 0.026 |
|         7 | 5/7/2013  | 0.027 |
|         7 | 6/7/2013  | 0.027 |
|         7 | 7/7/2013  | 0.027 |
|         7 | 8/7/2013  | 0.027 |
|         7 | 9/7/2013  | 0.027 |
|         7 | 10/7/2013 | 0.027 |
|         7 | 11/7/2013 | 0.027 |
|         7 | 12/7/2013 | 0.027 |
|         7 | 1/7/2014  | 0.027 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do that with CTE and SQL?

Comment: I should have mentioned it. SQL Server

Comment: I don't think I understand this... :)

Comment: Is there some logical relation between the EntryType and the number of rows you want returned for it? Or is this information that can be read from some sort of lookup table or something?

Comment: How does the price change from your input to your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this in a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx):

```
;with RecordCounts as (
    -- Establish row counts for each EntryType
    select 4 as EntryType, 1 as RecordCount
    union all select 5, 2
    union all select 6, 3
    union all select 7, 9
), PricesCte as (
    -- Get initial set of records
    select ID, p.EntryType, (select min(dt) from MyTable) as dt, price, 1 as RecordNum
    from MyTable p
        join RecordCounts c on p.EntryType = c.EntryType -- Only get rows where we've established a RecordCount
    -- Add records recursively according to RecordCount
    union all
    select ID, p.EntryType, dt, price, RecordNum + 1
    from PricesCte p
        join RecordCounts c on p.EntryType = c.EntryType
    where RecordNum + 1 <= c.RecordCount
)
select EntryType,
    dateadd(mm, row_number() over (order by EntryType, ID) - 1, dt) as dt,
    price
from PricesCTE
order by EntryType
option (maxrecursion 0) -- Infinite recursion, default limit is 100
```

Here is the [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f866/1) showing this work.

A couple of things:

- I would think that as the number of records climbs, this might perform better using a [Tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) rather than recursion to multiply records.  You'd cross-join with the Tally table and have the where clause limit the records according to the RecordCount
- I don't see how the pricing is supposed to change from the input to the output.
- I don't know where you are establishing the RecordCount per EntryType, so I've added that into another CTE.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH e (ID, EntryType, row, dt, Price, [Len])
AS
 (
  SELECT ID, EntryType, CASE EntryType WHEN 4 THEN 1
                                       WHEN 5 THEN 2
                                       WHEN 6 THEN 3
                                       WHEN 7 THEN 9 END AS row,
         dt, Price, 0 AS [Len] 
  FROM dbo.your_table
), x (ID, EntryType, row, dt, Price, [Len]) AS
 (
  SELECT ID, EntryType, row, dt, Price, 1
  FROM e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.ID, e.EntryType, e.row, e.dt, e.Price, x.[Len] + 1
  FROM e , x
  WHERE e.ID = x.ID AND e.row > x.[Len]
  )
SELECT EntryType, DATEADD(mm, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EntryType)-1, dt) AS dt, Price
FROM x
ORDER BY EntryType
```

Only thing I can't understand by what criteria to receive Price?

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a10b/1/0)

Comment: Virtually the same thing, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that can be done by CTE, since I can not tell any logic between EntryType and # of row.

For the question, I think it's easier to just build a temp table with number of row you want

```
DECLARE @Entry TABLE(EntryType INT, seq INT) 
INSERT INTO @Entry (EntryType , seq) VALUES
    (4,1)
    ,(5,1)
    ,(5,2)
    ,(6,1)
    ...
    ,(7,1)
    ..
    ,(7,9)
```

After that, a simple query will get the same result

```
SELECT  t.EntryType , DATEADD(MONTH,e.seq,  t.dt) as dt,t.Price 
FROM    YourTable t
INNER JOIN @Entry e 
    ON  t.EntryType = e.EntryType
```